# How to find the duraton of the video in .NET MAUI?

Tags: visual-studio, video, maui, filepicker

I am using .NET MAUI to code an app and am using `FilePicker` so the user can choose a video from their phone. I want to incorporate a code where it can distinguish whether the video is over 1 minute or not so if it is over a minute, it will display an alert saying, the video is not allowed since the duration of the video is over a minute. Is there any way to figure out the length of the video that the user chose from their phone gallery?

Comment: the linked answer is for Xamarin but the same approach should work in MAUI

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you!